# How can I stub out an audio interface in jack?

Tags: audio, jack

I've got a Tascam US-800 8-in/4-out audio interface that I use to record into Ardour. The setup is great, but I like to do my mastering and mixdowns elsewhere and I always have to drag around the audio interface because if it's not connected, Ardour won't open up. I'm wondering if there's some way to stub out the audio interface in jack so that I can trick ardour into thinking it's connected when it's really not. I looked into the connections, but I can't figure it out. When the interface is plugged in and ardour is running, this is what the connections pane looks like (I've collapsed ardour's connections because there are about 35 of them and the important part is the four system capture sources being used):

[jackd connection panel with US-800 connected http://www.bizlunch.net/craigslist/jackd_connections.png](http://www.bizlunch.net/craigslist/jackd_connections.png)

I imagine that there's some way to fake system/capture_[1-8], right? Any tips?